# Read data from latest folder in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

My S3 bucket contains multiple folders (Folder Name is in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format). I want to read the data from latest folder using Glue job(Scala). Could you please help with an approach to do this?

Thanks

Comment: S3 has no "latest file or folder"
 concept, your job to determine what the latest folder is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write code that lists the contents of the bucket and then determines which objects are the "latest".

Please note that **folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3**. For example, you could upload a file called `2022-10-29 08:20:33/foo.txt` and Amazon S3 will 'magically' create a folder with that date. Then, if the file is deleted, then the folder will magically 'disappear' (because it never existed).

When using the **Create folder** button in the S3 management console, a zero-length object is created with a filename (Key) equal to the name of the folder. This forces the folder to 'appear' even though it doesn't exist.

Also, folders don't maintain a date, so there is **no ability to determine the "latest folder"** based on a stored date value.

It is possible to **obtain a list of folders** by using `list_objects_v2(Delimiter='/', ...)`, in which case a list of `CommonPrefixes` is returned, which is the equivalent of listing the folder names at that level. You could do this to obtain all 'folder' names and then take the last one as being the latest.

Instead of relying on the date in the path, you could instead list all objects in the bucket and **use `LastModified` to determine which object is the latest** (which might be more reliable than using the path name).